# Storybook: Error after storysource addon installed

Tags: storybook

I would like to use the **storysource** 
- I've followed this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-storysource 
- I've installed the addon
- I've created a .storybook/webpack.config.js file this code
- I've put inside webpack.config.js

```
`module.exports = function({ config }) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.stories\.jsx?$/,
    loaders: [require.resolve("@storybook/source-loader")],
    enforce: "pre"
  });

  return config;
};
`
```

But I don't think that the addon works because I don't see anything in my story, maybe I need to enable something elsewhere?

#### Versions

"@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.1.11",

"@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.1.11",

"@storybook/html": "^5.1.11",

"@storybook/addon-storysource": "^5.2.8"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a webpack.config.js with your storybook then you will need the following in module.rules

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.stories\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: [require.resolve('@storybook/addon-storysource/loader')],
        enforce: 'pre',
      }
       ...
    ]
  }
```